# Chapter V of Grothendieck's EGA

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Grothedieck wrote, in the introduction of his EGA, Chapter V would be Procedes elementaires de construction de schemas(Elementary procedures for construction of schemes).
I wonder what he meant by it.
He wrote in his letter to Serre(10.31.1959) that he essentially finished chapter V. I can guess the contents of the other unpublished chapters, by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've got good news for you: you can actually *read* an online version of fragments of EGA V !

In the 1990's Piotr Blass, Joseph Blass and Stan Klas wrote articles giving their translation and interpretation  of Grothendieck's prenotes of part V of EGA.
They were published in *Ulam Quarterly*, a short-lived e-journal.
[Here](http://www.ulam.usm.edu/ulam_previous.html) is a link from which you can donload  all the articles  of the journal.
And [here](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/pubtexts.php)  is a page from which you can download all of EGA V as a PDF: look at the section "Links to EGA", last item before last.

Comment: That's great. So I guess he meant, by elementary procedures for construction of schemes, hyperplane sections and conic projections.

Comment: @MakotoKato No, those are the contents of the second edition of EGA V. You are asking about the contents of the first edition of EGA V, which were instead added to the second edition of EGA I.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia's page for the Éléments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_alg%C3%A9brique#Chapters) has a very nice table of the intended contents for both the first and second edition of each chapter.

The contents of the draft linked by Georges Elencwajg correspond to the plan for Chapter V in the 2nd edition of EGA. In this plan, EGA V is about *Complements sur les morphismes projectifs* (according to Wikipedia), i.e., a sequel to EGA IV.

The title *Procédés élémentaires de construction de schémas* corresponds to Chapter V in the **first plan** of the EGA, and apparently alludes to theorems for establishing that some interesting objects defined in terms of other structures are schemes as well. The fundamental method of proving this kind of fact is the "functor of points" approach (one may also call it "universal property" method). This method uses the fact that, sometimes, instead of describing a scheme $S$ as a locally ringed space, it's easier to describe which are the morphisms coming from an arbitrary scheme $T$ into this scheme, that is, the set $\mathrm{Hom}(T,S)$. This amounts to giving a contravariant functor which assigns a set to each scheme $T$: the set of morphisms from $T$ into the scheme which you want to build. Obviously, every scheme gives a functor of this kind, but it's not true that every such functor comes from a certain scheme (if this happens, the originating scheme is unique up to canonical isomorphism, by Yoneda's lemma). Grothendieck knew general conditions under which this reciprocal is true, and used them to unify many previous definitions into one.

For example, to construct the scheme $S = X\times Y$, product of two schemes $X, Y$,  we can ask ourselves what the morphisms from an arbitrary scheme $T$ to $X\times Y$ should be. Intuition coming from other contexts tells us that a morphism of this kind should be completely determined by its "components" (which are morphisms from $T$ to $X$ and to $Y$, separately), and every pair of morphisms $f_1: T\rightarrow X$, $f_2: T\rightarrow Y$ should be the components of some morphism into the product. This means that the set of morphisms from $T$ into $X\times Y$, $\mathrm{Hom}(T,X)$ is the set of pairs $(f_1,f_2)$ of a morphism $f_1$ from $T$ into $X$, together with a morphism $f_2$ from $T$ into $Y$. Consequently, $\mathrm{Hom}(T,X\times Y) = \mathrm{Hom}(T,X)\times \mathrm{Hom}(T,Y)$.

Hence, to obtain a scheme worthy of the name $X\times Y$, we could just prove that the functor $F$ given by $F(T)=\mathrm{Hom}(T,X)\times \mathrm{Hom}(T,Y)$ comes from some scheme (an existence proposition), which can be done by proving that $F$ has certain simple properties and then applying a general categorical theorem about existence. Uniqueness always comes from Yoneda's lemma.

Now, if Grothendieck changed his mind and all of this wasn't going to be treated in EGA V, did he move it to some other Chapter of the EGA? The answer is **yes**: he added it to the second version of EGA I, the only Chapter for which a second edition was ever published (also, the last one they finished). In my opinion, it's more logical this way. Procedures to define schemes are better placed in the general chapter about schemes, not 4 chapters later.